# Save a Sparse.LIL matrix to csv in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a 0.15M x 1.3M sparse.lil matrix that I want to store in a csv file. How can I save it in a csv file such that the resulting file size is smallest. According to me the best way will be to store it as

```
# output.csv

row1 col1 v11
row1 col2 v12
row1 col7 v17
row1 col9 v19
row2 col3 v23
row2 col6 v26
```

where values v<sub>ij</sub> are only non-zero values.

Is(are) there any direct function(s) that can do this? I suspect, doing it element-by-element will be extremely expensive!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sparse matrix formats just store the nonzero values, so writing those values will be the most compact option.  But `lil` is a list of lists format, which is not format you want to write.

But `coo` format stores its data in 3 attributes, row, col and data, which are the values you want.

`scipy.io` has a `savemat` format that handles sparse, but it's a MATLAB style file.  I'm not familiar with other options in `scipy.io`.

Are the values integers?  That will be easiest. Here I concatenate the 3 attribute arrays of the `coo` format into a Nx3 array, and then save it to a text file with the usual `np.savetxt`.

```
In [649]: M = sparse.eye(10).tolil()

In [650]: Mc = M.tocoo()

In [651]: Mc.row,Mc.col,Mc.data
Out[651]: 
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32),
 array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]))

In [652]: A=np.column_stack((Mc.row,Mc.col,Mc.data))

In [653]: A.shape
Out[653]: (10, 3)

In [655]: np.savetxt('lil.txt',A, fmt='%5.d',delimiter=',')

In [656]: cat lil.txt
    0,    0,    1
    1,    1,    1
    2,    2,    1
    ...
    7,    7,    1
    8,    8,    1
    9,    9,    1
```

Forming the array will be fast.  Writing it will take time, since `np.savetxt` iterates through the array rows, and does a line by line write.  But face it, all text files are written line by line, right?

```
 f.write(fmt % tuple(row))
```

This is the format of the `lil` array:

```
In [658]: M.rows
Out[658]: array([[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]], dtype=object)

In [659]: M.data
Out[659]: array([[1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0]], dtype=object)
```

Actually as created by `M` data values are float. And the `A` array is float also.  So I could saved with a float format, eg. `np.savetxt('lil.txt',A, fmt='%10.5f',delimiter=',')`

`np.savetxt('lil.txt',A, fmt='%10d,%10d,%10.5f')` writes 2 integer columns and a float.

If you don't like some of the integer index values as written, we may need to form `A` as a structured array.

====================

Another option is to write the lines directly.  Based on what I know of `np.savetxt`, this may be just as fast.

```
In [678]: with open('lil.txt','wb') as f:
    for x in zip(Mc.row,Mc.col,Mc.data):
        f.write(b'%5d,%5d,%10f\n'%x)
   .....:         

In [679]: cat lil.txt
    0,    0,  1.000000
    1,    1,  1.000000
    2,    2,  1.000000
    ...
    8,    8,  1.000000
    9,    9,  1.000000
```